# How to change programatically a span text inside a ProgressTemplate in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, updateprogress

I have the following UpdateProgress:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updCampos"
    DynamicLayout="true">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="carregando">
            <span id="sAguarde">Aguarde ...</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loading.gif" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I need to change in the code behind the text "Aguarde..." content that i nested inside the "sAguarde" span, but I don't know how to access this span. The  language is C#.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change your `<span>` control with Label as follows-

```
<asp:Label id="sAguarde" Text="Aguarde ..." runat="server" />
```

and access it from codebehind as follows-

```
Label progressMessageLabel = UpdateProgress1.FindControl("sAguarde") as Label;
if (progressMessageLabel != null)
{
    progressMessageLabel.Text = "something";
}
```

Comment: How about accessing it from a MasterPage codebehind, where the UpdateProgress is located in a Content page?

Answer (score 5):

You could change the span to a serverside control:

```
<span id="sAguarde" runat="server">Aguarde ...</span>
```

Then you can access it from the codebehind:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (update) // globally declared update boolean to check if the page is being updated 
    {
        HtmlGenericControl sAguarde = (HtmlGenericControl) UpdateProgress1.FindControl("sAguarde");
        sAguarde.InnerHTML = "Hi";
    }
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

But note that the span's id will be rendered using ASP.NET control naming conventions.

For full context, see: [Changing the contents of the UpdateProgress control](https://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2007/11/12/changing-the-contents-of-the-updateprogress-control.aspx)

Comment: This will not work as the span is inside update progress, you cannot access it directly